# how to use mapproxy to serve WMS from reprojected google maps tiles

Tags: google-maps, web-mapping, tiles, proxy, mapproxy

how to use mapproxy to serve WMS from reprojected google maps tiles, i have searched for docs, but there's no docs which describe how to add google maps as source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically it is very simple to use Google tiles as source for WMS. You can do this with the following MapProxy config:

```
services:
  demo:
  tms:
  wms:
    md: 
      title: MapProxy WMS Server

sources:
  gm:
    type: tile
    url: http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@0&hl=en&x=%(x)s&y=%(y)s&z=%(z)s
    grid: gm_grid

grids:
  gm_grid:
    base: GLOBAL_MERCATOR
    origin: ul

caches:
  gm_cache:
    grids: [gm_grid]
    sources: [gm]
    cache:
      type: file
      directory_layout: tms

layers:
  - name: gm_layer
    title: Test of using GM tiles
    sources: [gm_cache]
```

But as mentioned above - you are allowed to access the tiles only through Google API.

Answer (score 3):

MapProxy supports  WMS sources (1.0.0–1.3.0)& TMS/WMTS sources.

Google does not have an WMS service. It has its own tiles, and according to Google's Terms & Conditions, you are allowed to access the tiles only through their API.

This is why you cannot use MapProxy with Google Maps as a source.

Comment: but from this slide http://fr.scribd.com/doc/102823641/Mapproxy-Tutorial#page=9 , they said the possibility to add custom tile like google maps tiles.

Comment: Yes, you can use TMS to cache Google Tiles and then publish them as WMS service, but that would violate Google's TOS, so you should make sure that you can have right for using Google Maps Tiles

Comment: @VietThanhLe i know that it could violate Google TOS, but I'm trying just to make a personal experiment, but i didn't found how to add google maps as source for custom tiles.

Comment: You will need to have tile url, namely the url to a single tile with x/y/x value like this pseudo one: http://tiles.googlemaps.com/{x}/{y}/{z}.png (Use Firebug/Firefox to get the real one), and then you just need read thoroughly MapProxy's documentation to get your task done.